# Azure Wordpress deny xmlrpc

Tags: azure, wordpress, xml-rpc, azure-web-app-service

What is the proper way to deny xmlrpc on a Microsoft azure IIS
since I don't have a .htacess , but a web.config file what should I add to it to deny access(ping back) to xmlrpc.php

Comment: have you tried the WordPress Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-xml-rpc/

Comment: I installed that plugin and another one that should deny/diable xml rpc, But dont seem to be working, when i hit www.mysite.com/xmlrpc.php  i still get a ''XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only.'' meaning its still working ?

Answer (score 1):

using the web.config file you can disable access to url sequences such as xmlrpc.php using IIS Request Filtering (for more information on the additional options see - http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering).

To solve your problem add the highlighted section to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <denyUrlSequences>
                <add sequence="xmlrpc.php" />
            </denyUrlSequences>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This example will return a 404 response to any client requesting the resource and will log a 404.5 (URL Sequence Denied) status in your server log file.

Cheers

Andrew